# How to setup server with Domain name on local ubuntu14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, vhosts

How to setup **domain name** at local machine on **lamp**?

Comment: Hello ! Go through this link will sure helps to you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:
1. Copy **`sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf  /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.conf`**
2.Edit yourdoamin.conf: **`sudo gedit  /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.conf`**
3.Configure DomainName and IP Address:

```
   <VirtualHost 12.0.0.12:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdoamin.com
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourprojectroot

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

save and exit.
4.Make entry in **hosts** file edit:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   pramodkharade-desktop
127.0.0.12 www.yourdomain.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

save and exit.

5.Enable yourdoamin.conf:

```
sudo a2ensite yourdomain.conf
```

6. Restart apache:

sudo service apache2 restart

7. Goto Browser and enter yourdoamin.com and press Enter