# Custom API and cunsuming in php?

Tags: php, rest, curl

I want to write Web services(REST) and Consuming using Curl in php.

```
$books = array(
        "java"=>"222",
        "php"=>"333",
        "c"=>"111",
        "AngularJS"=>"111"
        );
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to write Web service using REST in PHP? I am new in Software Development . lets suppose, I have sample data like above.

Comment: This is not how SO is meant to be used. You need to ask a specific question after trying solutions yourself, not just state what you want to do and hope for the code to magically appear.

Comment: you can go with slim framework for Web services.

Comment: Save your data in MySQL and upload the file "api.php" from [php-crud-api](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api). Disclaimer: I'm the author. NB: There are also sample clients in the "examples" directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build your API in PHP check [Slim Framework](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html)

It is a good framework and has a great documentation. I suggest you to use existing solutions because building your API from scratch needs a lot of time and expertise

Also [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) is a good tool to define/design your rest endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

To create the API - do the following:

```
<?php
$books = array(
    "java"=>"222",
    "php"=>"333",
    "c"=>"111",
    "AngularJS"=>"111"
);

return json_encode($books);
```

To use the returned value - you would do the opposite:

```
$books = json_decode($books_json);
```

Answer (score -1):

First define URL END point for API and client url.

```
ex:API: http://www.customapi.com/java
   Client URI: http://www.clientcustomapi.com/
```

**API Snippet:** 
**index.php**

```
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
include('functions.php');
//process client request
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $price = get_price($name);
    if(empty($price)){
        //book not found
        deliveryResponse(200,"Book not found",NULL);
    }else{
        //response book price
        deliveryResponse(200,"Book found",$price);
    }
}else{
    //invalid request
    deliveryResponse(400,"invalid Request",NULL);
}
```

**function.php**

```
function get_price($find){
    $books = array(
        "java"=>"222",
        "php"=>"333",
        "c"=>"111"
        );
    foreach ($books as $book => $price) {
        # code...
        if($book==$find){
            return $price;
            break;
        }
    }

}
function deliveryResponse($status,$status_message,$data){
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
    $response['status'] = $status;
    $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
    $response['data'] = $data;

    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
```

**Client Snippet:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Book Price</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="bookprice">
    <label>Book Name:</label><input type="text" name="book" id="book">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //simple Request
    $name = $_POST['book'];
    //resource address
    $url ="http://www.customapi.com/$name";

    //send request to resource
    $client = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //get response from resource
    $response = curl_exec($client);
    $result = json_decode($response);
    if($result->data !=null){
        echo $result->data;
    }else{
        echo"No record found";
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!Solution is very simple but same solution would have implemented in slim framework instead of core PHP. it could be better.

Comment: Thanks for solutions its working but how we can set url(domain)?

Comment: You mean to say virtual host? refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144016/how-to-setup-server-with-domain-name-on-local-ubuntu14-04/38144370#38144370

Comment: This answer is valid and answers the question, I'm curious as to why the downvote?